# Using bibtex, how to combine two references such that they are mentioned as one in the bibliography

Tags: bibtex

Instead of

[1] reference 1
[2] reference 2

How can I have

[1] reference 1; reference 2

?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Looks like a dupe to me (probably should have spotted this earlier!)

Answer (score 6):

Found it!
If the references have `key1`, `key2`. Citing with a star combines them.

instead of `\cite{key1, key2}`, using `\cite{key1, *key2}` gives the desired result.

Cheers.

Note: This was achieved when using revtex 4.1, which implements a syntax similar to `mcite`. The same can be achieved in standard classes by loading `mcite`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mcite}
\begin{document}
\cite{article-full,*book-full}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How does this solution address the stated objective of wanting a citation call-out of the form "[1] reference 1; reference 2"?

Comment: @Mico when you put an asterisk in front of the second key, in the references at the end of the document you will have a combined bibliographic entry---which is what I wanted.