# Combining references as one in Biblatex running bibtex as backend

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-citations, biblatex-chem

Combining citations as one has been discussed earlier in the following questions,

[Combining-citations-at-some-instance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15747/combining-citations-at-some-instance)

[Combine two references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239106/using-bibtex-how-to-combine-two-references-such-that-they-are-mentioned-as-one)

However, my case is a little special I guess. I using `biblatex` with  `bibtex` as backend  and a customized `.bbx` file, namely `chem-wiley-JRS`. (This is a  modified version from [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright)'s implementation of biblatex-chem for a specific journal.)

Here is my usage:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,biblabel=brackets,chaptertitle,pageranges=false,style=chem-wiley-JRS]{biblatex}
```

Now I seek to combine two references, and tried `mcite` and `mciteplus`.
In both cases I obtain the error,

```
line 167: Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'mcite'. \blx@packageincompatibility
: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
: Overwriting file `./general.bib'.
: Tab has been converted to Blank Space.
line 59: Citation '*B02' on page 1 undefined
line 59: Citation '*B02' on page 1 undefined
line 59: Citation '*D03' on page 1 undefined
: There were undefined references.
: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):(biblatex) biblatex_test_citation(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

And the output,

[image: output image here]

I need some direction about how to combine two or more references in my case.

Full code is below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{mcite}

% For references: Using biblatex 
%--------------------------------
% chem-wiley-JRS is the bbx file 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,biblabel=brackets,chaptertitle,pageranges=false,style=chem-wiley-JRS]{biblatex}
%--------------------------------
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{general.bib}
    @article{A01,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {1983},
        title = {Alpha},
        journal = {Some random journal},
        volume = {1},
        number = {3},
        pages = {52-56}     
    }
    @article{B02,
        author = {Buthor, B.},
        year = {1934},
        title = {Bravo},
        journal = {J. Color Comput.},
        volume = {4},
        number = {7},
        pages = {6-13}
    }

    @article{D03,
        author = {Duthor, D.},
        year = {1985},
        title = {Delta in a  Delta},
        journal = {Appl. Color Science},
        volume = {1},
        number = {3},
        pages = {401-502}       
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{general.bib}
%--------------------------------

% Title and author information -------------------
\title{Towards testing }
\author{John Doe}
%-------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem Ipsum\autocite{A01,*B02,*D03} is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\autocite{A01,*B02} Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

`chem-wiley-JRS.bbx` is the following.

```
\ProvidesFile{chem-wiley-JRS.bbx}[2018/10/18 v1.1w biblatex bibliography style]
% This file is derived from the 'chem-rsc' bbx file. Modified on 06/20/2019 %
%% Original author details.
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------
%% biblatex-chem --- A set of biblatex implementation for
%%   chemistry-related bibliography styles
%% Maintained by Joseph Wright
%% E-mail: joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk
%% Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
%% See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------
%% 

% Load the standard style to avoid copy-pasting unnecessary material
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric-comp}

% New options
\newtoggle{bbx:articletitle}
\newtoggle{bbx:chaptertitle}
\newtoggle{bbx:pageranges}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{articletitle}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:articletitle}{#1}%
}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{chaptertitle}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:chaptertitle}{#1}%
}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{pageranges}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:pageranges}{#1}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyOption{biblabel}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{plain}
    {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{##1}}
    {%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{brackets}
        {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{##1}}}%
        {%
          \ifstrequal{#1}{dot}
            {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{##1\adddot\midsentence}}
            {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{##1}}}%
        }%
    }%
}

% Alter settings that carry through from biblatex
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions
  {
    date         = year  ,
    doi          = false ,
    eprint       = false ,
    giveninits   = true  ,
    isbn         = false ,
    maxnames     = 999   ,
    maxcitenames = 2     ,
    pageranges   = true  ,
    url          = false
  }

% Modify the name format
\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex_legacy}
  {
    \DeclareNameFormat{default}{%
      \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
      \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
    }
  }
  {
    \DeclareNameFormat{default}{%
      \nameparts{#1}%
      \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}%
      \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
    }
  }

% Custom field formats 
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  DOI\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}%
}

%ORIGINAL-
%\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibitalic{#1}\isdot}

%Modified for wiley-JRS
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[patent]{number}{\mkgroupeddigits{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:pageranges}{#1}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, incollection, proceedings]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[patent]{type}{%
  \ifbibstring{#1}
    {\mkbibitalic{\bibstring{#1}}}
    {\mkbibitalic{#1}}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}

% FOLLOWING ARE CHANGED FOR wiley-JRS ------------------------% 

% Article %
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}


% Book %
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{volume}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

% incollection %
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{volume}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

% proceedings %
\DeclareFieldFormat[proceedings]{volume}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[proceedings]{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[collection]{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[manual]{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
    \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%
}


% maybe the above modifications are not  complete. 

%-------------------------------------------------------------%

% Simple modifications to punctuation, etc.
\renewcommand*{\begrelateddelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{\addcomma\space#1}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \renewrobustcmd*{\finalandcomma}{}%
}

% Bibliography strings
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  chapter   = ch\adddot          ,
  edition   = edn\adddot         ,
  patentus  = US Pat\adddot      ,
  phdthesis = Ph.D.\space Thesis
}

% Bibliography macros
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
      \clearname{editor}%
      \newunit
    }%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{editorstrg}{%
  \printtext[editortype]{\bibstring{editor}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{%
  \printfield{eventtitle}%
  \printfield{venue}%
  \newunit
  \printeventdate
  \newunit
}

\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \newunit
  \printdate
  \newunit
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
    }%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
    \newunit\newblock
    }}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {%
      \printfield{doi}%
      \clearfield{doi}%
    }%
    {%
      \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
        {}
        {\clearfield{doi}}%
    }%
}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
}

%ADDED 
%\renewbibmacro*{key+title}{%
%  \printlist{key}%
%  \newunit
%  \printlist{title}%
%  \newunit
%}


\newbibmacro*{related:translatedas}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
      {\printfield{issn}}
      {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  }%
}

% Specialised functions for manipulating data, where the biblatex
% kernel does not provide a suitable function.
\newcommand*\mkgroupeddigits[1]{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {%
      \bbx@digits@ifmorethanfour{#1}
        {%
          \def\@tempa{}%
          \bbx@digits@separate{}#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
        }
        {#1}%
    }%
    {#1}%
}

\newcommand*\bbx@digits@ifmorethanfour[1]{%
  \bbx@digits@ifmorethanfour@aux#1\@empty\@empty\@empty\@empty
    \@empty\@nil
}

\def\bbx@digits@ifmorethanfour@aux#1#2#3#4#5\@nil{%
 \ifx\@empty#5\@empty
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
}

\newcommand*\bbx@digits@separate[4]{%
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \bbx@digits@print#1\relax
  \else
    \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
      \bbx@digits@print\@empty\@empty#1#2\relax
    \else
      \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
        \bbx@digits@print\@empty#1#2#3\relax
      \else
        \bbx@digits@separate@aux{#1#2#3#4}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

\def\bbx@digits@separate@aux#1\fi\fi\fi{%
  \fi\fi\fi\bbx@digits@separate{#1}%
}

\newcommand*\bbx@digits@print[4]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{#1}%
  #2#3%
  \ifx\relax#4\relax\else
    \addnbthinspace
    \expandafter\bbx@digits@print\expandafter#4%
  \fi
}

% New bibliography drivers, using the required order of fields. These
% are mainly copied from standard.bbx then modified.
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:articletitle}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \newunit
    }
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{collection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:chaptertitle}
    {\usebibmacro{title}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \setunit*{\newunitpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:chaptertitle}
    {\usebibmacro{title}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{manual}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{patent}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \iflistundef{location}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \printlist[][-\value{listtotal}]{location}}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byholder}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

Comment: The `mcite` package is incompatible with `biblatex`, so you can not use it here. AFAICS dynamic entry sets need Biber, so if you want `mcite`-like sets you need to use Biber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `mcite` (like most other citation or bibliography packages) is incompatible with `biblatex`, I'm afraid. You can't load both packages together in the same document, `biblatex` will issue an error about it sooner or later (even if you ignore the error, there is zero chance that `biblatex` will be able to make use of `mcite`'s interface).

`biblatex` offers its own emulation of `mcite` features, which it calls dynamic entry sets.

In versions prior to `biblatex` 3.15 dynamic entry sets were only available with the Biber backend. From v3.15 on they can be used with Biber and BibTeX. You will also need to load the `mcite` compatibility modus if you want to be able to use `\mcite` and its `*` syntax.

Even though Biber is no longer strictly required, it is still recommended to switch to Biber. On an up-to-date system switching to Biber is as easy as changing `backend=bibtex` to `backend=biber` and running ([or telling your editor to run](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)) Biber intead of BibTeX.

This issue is independent of the exact citation style you use, so I'll use this simplified MWE.

By default `\mcite` behaves like cite and there are multicite versions for other commands as well `\parencite` (`\mparencite`), `\footcite` (`\mfootcite`), `\textcite` (`\mtextcite`) and from `biblatex` 3.15 also for `\autocite` (`\mautocite`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, mcite, style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum \mautocite{setA,*sigfridsson,*worman,*nussbaum}
Dolor \autocite{setA}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Set citations.]

Updated for `biblatex` 3.15 changes. See edit history if you are using an older version.

Comment: The `mcite` stuff was in when `biblatex` was BibTeX-only: don't you just have to pre-define the set?

Comment: @JosephWright I'll have a closer look to see what it looked like. Maybe it just got culled when the backend code was merged.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry for late check of your comment as well. Works as mentioned. :-)

Comment: @JosephWright The earliest mentions of `\defbibentryset` and `mcite` emulation in the `biblatex` docs all say that those features are Biber only. I found a very early version of `biblatex` that didn't yet have the `mcite` emulation feature and there the docs mention that entry sets (similar to `mcite`) are supported, but need to be define in the `.bib` file. So I don't think `biblatex` ever supported dynamic sets with  BibTeX. But at least naively I would have thought that it might be possible to get it by writing the set entry to `-blx.bib`. ...

Comment: If you have an idea and want to take this, feel free to do so, otherwise I'll have a look, but I'm not sure if I can get it done (and it's not that high up my list).

Comment: @moewe  : On a side note, I was using `\autocite` for citation to appear in the text as a superscript (without a square bracket). Can you suggest something to have that with `\mcite`. (Maybe some global option for `\usepackage[]{biblatex}`, which I am looking for now.)

Comment: @ankit7540 See the edit. I might be missing something, but maybe `\mautocite` should be defined by default...

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/921

Comment: @moewe Oh, they were never dynamic: my point was you can do `mcite`-like stuff with an appropriate 'per paper' `.bib` file to define sets.

Comment: @moewe : Thanks a lot for the edit.